# Java Classpath Problems

Tags: java, compiler-construction, classpath

I've compiled and I am now trying to run [this](http://andreas-hess.info/programming/webcrawler/index.html) program from the terminal in OSX and Fendora using the following command from within the ie directory:

`java ie.moguntia.webcrawler.Psucker http://www.wikipedia.org test`

However I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ie/moguntia/webcrawler/Psucker
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ie.moguntia.webcrawler.Psucker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I haven't ran applications that used packages from the command line before so I am therefore unable to figure out the error.

I have attempted to set the classpath using `export CLASSPATH=.` so that the current directory would be added to the classpath.

The directory structure is as follows:

`ie/moguntia/webcrawler/`

Comment: does the CWD has the required jar?

Comment: There are no require jar files. I should note that this runs fine on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where your compiled classes are located, you need to include this location in the java command, e.g. if they are in the `classes` directory:

```
java -cp classes ie.moguntia.webcrawler.PSucker http://www.wikipedia.org test
```

or if they are in the current directory:

```
java -cp . ie.moguntia.webcrawler.PSucker http://www.wikipedia.org test
```

or just

```
java ie.moguntia.webcrawler.PSucker http://www.wikipedia.org test
```

Here's how I was able to run this (unzip, cd to directory, compile, find classes, run):

```
(13:55:52) ~/Desktop/temp → ll
total 32
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Nils.Winkler  staff    14K 12 Mär 13:41 multiweb.zip

(13:56:01) ~/Desktop/temp → unzip multiweb.zip -d multiweb
Archive:  multiweb.zip
   creating: multiweb/CVS/
   creating: multiweb/ie/
   creating: multiweb/ie/CVS/
   creating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/
   creating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/CVS/
   creating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/threads/
   creating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/threads/CVS/
  inflating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/threads/ControllableThread.java  
  inflating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/threads/MessageReceiver.java  
  inflating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/threads/ObjectQueue.java  
  inflating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/threads/Queue.java  
  inflating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/threads/ThreadController.java  
   creating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/webcrawler/
   creating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/webcrawler/CVS/
  inflating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/webcrawler/PSucker.java  
  inflating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/webcrawler/PSuckerThread.java  
  inflating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/webcrawler/SaveURL.java  
  inflating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/webcrawler/URLQueue.java  
  inflating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/webcrawler/WSDLCrawler.java  
  inflating: multiweb/ie/moguntia/webcrawler/WSDLCrawlerThread.java 

(13:56:08) ~/Desktop/temp → cd multiweb

(13:56:57) ~/Desktop/temp/multiweb → javac ie/moguntia/webcrawler/*.java
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

(13:57:11) ~/Desktop/temp/multiweb → find . -name *.class
./ie/moguntia/threads/ControllableThread.class
./ie/moguntia/threads/MessageReceiver.class
./ie/moguntia/threads/Queue.class
./ie/moguntia/threads/ThreadController.class
./ie/moguntia/webcrawler/PSucker.class
./ie/moguntia/webcrawler/PSuckerThread.class
./ie/moguntia/webcrawler/SaveURL.class
./ie/moguntia/webcrawler/URLQueue.class
./ie/moguntia/webcrawler/WSDLCrawler.class
./ie/moguntia/webcrawler/WSDLCrawlerThread.class

(13:57:18) ~/Desktop/temp/multiweb → java ie.moguntia.webcrawler.PSucker http://www.wikipedia.org test
[0] http://www.wikipedia.org
```

Comment: I've added the directory structure to the question.

Comment: Check the classname - it's `PSucker` with a capital S. I've changed my examples.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I've been running PSucker on my terminal.

Comment: Can you make sure that the class files are actually in the ie/moguntia/webcrawler directory? I unzipped the downloaded package into the multiweb folder, and I can run the command `java ie.moguntia.webcrawler.PSucker http://www.wikipedia.org test` from there without problems. I didn't have to provide any classpath when running from the same directory.

Comment: What's the output of `find . -name *.class`?

Comment: Please see above, I was able to run it without any issues. Can you repeat the steps that I did above?

Comment: I repeated the steps above and it works on my home OSX system just not on the university system, which means that this must be a permissions problem. I'll mark your answer correct.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you run it from *outside* the ie directory.

Note that relying on the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is generally not recommended; instead explicitly put the classpath on hte command line using the `-cp` switch

Comment: I've tried running it from the directory above `ie` to no avail.

Comment: @Ash: well, it's never going to wrok from within, that's for sure. But if fixing that does not help, it might be a matter of file access rights.